# Pick elements from list based on a selection criteria which involves previously selected element

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.5

I have a list with numbers which are actually distances, say 0.4,1.2, 5.6,7.8,8.9,10.2, ..... 10000.25.

Now I would like to select every element from this list such that the distance between each element is at least x metres. So for x = 2.5 metres, the new list would have:

0.4,5.6, 8.9,.....10000.25

Thanks.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, your problem would not have a single solution. 
1.2,7.8,10.2, ..... 10000.25 would also be correct.
Are there any other conditions your solution needs to meet?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that.

```
IEnumerable<float> MyFunction(IEnumerable<float> input, float minDistance)
{
    bool isFirst = true;
    float previousValue = 0f; // will be rewritten immediately.
    foreach(var value in input)
    {
        if (isFirst || (Math.Abs(value - previousValue) >= minDistance))
        {
            isFirst = false;
            previousValue = value;
            yield return value;
        } 
    }
}
```

Or a generic version

```
    public delegate bool MyTest<in T>(T previousValue, T currentValue);

    IEnumerable<T> MyFunction<T>(IEnumerable<T> input, MyTest<T> test)
    {
        var isFirst = true;
        var previousValue = default(T); // will be rewritten immediately.
        foreach (var value in input)
        {
            if (isFirst || test(previousValue, value))
            {
                isFirst = false;
                previousValue = value;
                yield return value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Where the call is :

```
float[] t = {1, 2, 3};
var result = MyFunction(t, (previewsValue, currentValue) => Math.Abs(previewsValue - currentValue) >= 1.2);
```